# Audit Changes to Variant Types

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft access, I am creating an audit table that tracks changes to the DB. We have it working for data points that are text boxes. However, we track a few categorical (variant) data points for each item in the db. The audit log doesn't seem to work for just this one specifically. I believe this is because .oldvalue doesn't work on variants, but I don't know what the alternative is.

Basically when I make a change, and I go to the audit log, oldvalue == newvalue if I change one of the variants. So if I change the "type" of the data point from financial to managerial, old == managerial and new == managerial in my audit log.

I have attached the code below in hopes that someone smarter than me can help me figure this one out.

Thank you very much in advance.

after doing research I found no alternative to .oldvalue in access.

```
    Select Case UserAction
        Case "EDIT"
            For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
                If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                    If (TypeName(ctl.Value) <> "Variant()") Then
                        If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                            With rst
                                .AddNew
                                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                                ![UserName] = strUserID
                                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                                ![Action] = UserAction
                                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                                ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                                ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                                ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                                .Update
                            End With
                        End If
                    End If
                    If (TypeName(ctl.Value) = "Variant()") Then
                            With rst
                                .AddNew
                                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                                ![UserName] = strUserID
                                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                                ![Action] = UserAction
                                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                                ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                                ![OldValue] = Join(ctl.OldValue, ",")
                                ![NewValue] = Join(ctl.Value, ",")
                                .Update
                            End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next ctl
        Case Else
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserName] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                ![Action] = UserAction
                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                .Update
            End With
    End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

I expect in my audit log for oldvalue to be financial and newvalue to be managerial. However, both old and new are managerial .Leading me to believe that .oldvalue isn't functioning.

Comment: I did a test with TypeName function on a declared Variant variable. It returns "Empty". Why would you expect TypeName on Value of a control object to return "Variant()"?

Comment: @June7 that's a good point. Sorry, I am kind of new to this and jerry rigged some code I found online. What would be the alternative structure then? I'm mostly following your logic but it's a bit confusing. Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Not sure what you want to verify. Type of control (textbox, combobox, label) or type of data (string, number, date) or whether the control has any data at (Is Null)?